# How to assign values in one array to another in java

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I have two arrays and I am trying to assign the values of one array, i.e. arrayOne[0] should be equal to the corresponding index in arrayTwo[0].
I am trying to do this using a forloop so that it loops through the the index of one array assigning the values sequentially.
so far I have:
for (int a =0; a< arrayOne.length; ++) {
// this sets the an int that loops through the value of the arrays(both arrayOne and arrayTwo are the same length)
I am lost however after this how to create the for loop which assigns index 0 = 0 and then incrementally step through this.

I know this is a very basic question but I am, as my name suggests, struggling to learn coding.

Comment: arrayTwo[a] = arrayOne[a];

Answer (score 2):

> I am lost however after this how to create the for loop which assigns index 0 = 0 and then incrementally step through this.

There are many ways to copy arrays.  But since you specifically asked for a for loop solution, just create a new array of the same size and use a `for loop` as shown to index them.

```
int [] a = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
int [] b = new int[a.length];
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
     b[i] = a[i]; // this copies element a[i] to b[i] where i is the index.
}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(b));
```

Prints

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```